# Android: Determine what pixels an Android Path occupies

Tags: android, path, interpolation

I have a a drawing program where a user can trace with their finger, and in a manner similar to the [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html) program, a series of `Path`'s are drawn to represent the lines.

Now, I am doing some collision detection to allow the user to enter an 'erase' mode and delete selected lines, and am trying to determine how to track the individual pixels of the `Path`.  Essentially, I am tracking the `RectF` that encompasses the `Path`, and if the `RectF` is intersected when in erase mode, I'd like to then do pixel-by-pixel intersection tests. So, I need to create some structure for storing the pixels, likely a two dimensional array where each element will be a 1 or 0, based on whether or not the underlying pixel is occupied by the drawn `Path`.

It is this last part that I am struggling with. While the user is drawing the line, I am feeding the passed X/Y values in as control points for a quadratic bezier curve via `Path.quadTo()`.  The problem is that while `Path` uses these points to represent a continuous line, I am only being fed discontinous X/Y points from the touch device.  Essentially, I need a way to duplicate what the `Path` object itself is doing, and take the passed X/Y points and interpolate that into a continous curve, but as a set of X/Y coordinates rather than a `Path` object...

Any pointers to get started on this?

Thanks

EDIT/MORE:

Ok, so as I mentioned, each `Path` is created (roughly) using the method found in [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html), which means that it is a series of segments, where each segment is a quadratic bezier curve. Given that I know P0, P1 and P2 when I add these curved segments to the larger Path, I can determine the X/Y coordinates along the curve with:

[image]

So, my only problem now is determining a 'continous' set of adjacent X/Y coordinates, such that there are no gaps in this set that a user's finger might pass through without hitting one. This would mean determining each X/Y point at 1 pixel intervals.  As the above formula would yield points at an infinite number of intervals, given the values of T ranging from 0 through 1, any idea how to programmatically determine the right values of T that will yield points at 1 pixel intervals?

Answer (score 0):

I would do all collision detection using not curves or pixels, but just lines, it's much easier to find intersecting lines, i.e. the intersection of two sequential x/y coordinates of the user's swipe, and the lines of existing lines

Comment: As I mention, the existing 'lines' are a series of curves, described as quadratic beziers... how would I convert these curves (potentially swirls, circles, etc) into lines that I can then check to see if a line from sequntial X/Y swipe coordinates match?